# How to input a word

Tags: search, input

(I am using Python 3)

I want to create a program in which depending on the word (not a string) I wrote, different results are shown.

For example, I have two documents (beer.txt and wine.txt). I do not know how to make a way in which if I input beer, the content of beer.txt will appear and if I write wine...

```
  x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
if x = beer:
    f = open ('beer.txt', 'r')
    message = f.read()
    print (message)
    f.close()
elif x = wine:
    f = open ('wine.txt', 'r')
    message = f.read()
    print (message)
    f.close()
```

Obviously, this is so wrong and does not work. I have tried also:

```
while True:
    if imput("Product? ") == "beer":
        f = open ('beer.txt', 'r')
        message = f.read()
        print (message)
        f.close()
```

But nothing seems to work.

Help me, please

Comment: I know I was very brief. I am able to reproduce a txt with a function (f.read, write etc.). but the problem is that I don't know if I have to use Input?

Comment: I have already used eval(input) and I can do it, but the problem is that I do not want to write a string

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

First, beer and wine are not defined in the snippet you sent, second to compare values you do not use '='. The correct syntax in  python is like this:

```
x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
beer = 0
wine = 1
if x == beer:
    f = open ('beer.txt', 'r')
    message = f.read()
    print (message)
    f.close()
elif x == wine:
    f = open ('wine.txt', 'r')
    message = f.read()
    print (message)
    f.close()
```

I did add the variables wine and beer just show you the proper syntax of comparing values.